# iOS set image of specific index

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, indexing, thumbnails

I want to display image at specific image in scrollview on click on thumbnail. As per selection of thumbnail I want to display image. I am just using ScrollView, then how can I solve that?
my code of collectionview is,

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
    customcell *cell=[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[cell nyimage]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[temparr objectAtIndex:indexPath.section * 1 + indexPath.row]]];
    return cell;

}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
    {
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.gallerycollection indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedIndexPath.row];
        NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"jpg"];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
        GalleryImageScrollViewController *gallerydetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        gallerydetailViewController.FullScreenImageScroller=image;
    }
}
```

scrollview is,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSMutableArray *mutablearray = [NSMutableArray array];
    data=[MyDatabase new];
    slideImages=[data OpenMyDatabase:@"SELECT pic_name_big FROM interior":@"pic_name_big"];
    [mutablearray addObjectsFromArray:slideImages];
    temparr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    temparr=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:mutablearray];
    [self putImageViewsInScrollView:[temparr count]];
    self.FullScreenImageScroller.delegate=self;

}




-(void) putImageViewsInScrollView:(int)numberOfImageViews
{
   for(int i=0 ;i<numberOfImageViews; i++)
    {
        fullScreenImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[temparr objectAtIndex:i]]];
        fullScreenImageView.frame = CGRectMake((WIDTH_OF_IMAGE * i)  , 0, WIDTH_OF_IMAGE, HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE);
        [self.FullScreenImageScroller addSubview:fullScreenImageView];
    }
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(WIDTH_OF_SCROLL_PAGE * ([temparr count]), HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE)];
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
    [self.FullScreenImageScroller scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,0,WIDTH_OF_IMAGE,HEIGHT_OF_IMAGE) animated:NO];


}
```

Comment: Just modify the contentOffset value based on the index you want to display. Whats the problem ?

Comment: thanks for your reply mate. I want to open full screen image when i click on a thumbnail. and bigger image should be opened in a scrollview that i have already coded.

Comment: Where do you click on the thumbnail ? And where are these thumbnails ? Are they in another view ?

Comment: those thumbnails are in collection view . I have edited the code above .Please refer that once.

Comment: If I understand correctly this "customcell" object represents your thumbnails ? How are you handling clicks/selections on them ? Can you add this code as well please.

Comment: yes. customcell respresent to thumbnails. and I am handling clicks on thumbnails by "indexPathsForSelectedItems" in prepare for segue. I have already added that code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your code, if you change the offset of the scrollview based on the index of your thumbnail, it should work:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
        {
            if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) 
            {
                NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [[self.gallerycollection indexPathsForSelectedItems] objectAtIndex:0];

                NSString *imageNameToLoad = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", selectedIndexPath.row];
                NSString *pathToImage = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageNameToLoad ofType:@"jpg"];
                UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathToImage];
                GalleryImageScrollViewController *gallerydetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];

                //set offset of scroll view
                gallerydetailViewController.FullScreenImageScroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(WIDTH_OF_IMAGE*selectedIndexPath.row, 0);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why not what is happening ?

Comment: even if i click on any image in sollcetion view. it just keeps displaying the first image in scrollview

Comment: Can you please add your full code, preferably the whole files in a link somewhere, its hard to see what is going on. I have just tried to give you directions.

Comment: gimme your mail id. wil mail it to you. and please make changes in same file if possible and send it back :) thanks

Comment: I cannot run that, so cannot really see what is going on. Probably you have messed up the indexes somewhere. Just try to put some breakpoints. Make sure when you click on the thumbnail, you get the correct index back. Then make sure you use that index to set the contentOffset of the scrollView.

Comment: m getting correct index of image in NSString *imageNameToLoad. but I dnt knw how to pass index in scrollview

Comment: You get your scrollview with: gallerydetailViewController.FullScreenImageScroller ? right ? Whats the problem to pass the index to it ?

Comment: thats what m saying buddy. its just showing tha\e same image . the first one.

Comment: You are getting images in 3 different places ? In viewDidLoad of both of your view controllers and in prepareForSegue:sender ? Are they all the same?

Comment: yes. they all are the same. but view controller have thumbnail and scrollview contain normal bigger images.

Comment: Can you verify that the 'selectedIndexPath.row' value is the index that you are expecting ? Also, how is GalleryImageScrollViewController added to the storyboard ?

Comment: yes. selectedIndexPath.row gives me the actual index value that i am expecting. GalleryImageScrollViewController was added normally as view controller and scroll view was added to that.

Comment: They only thing I can think of is that for some reason viewDidLoad's method of the scrollview controller is getting called after prepareForSegue:sender. Can you verify that this does not happen ?